# Copy to clipboard on Windows Phone 8.1 apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, clipboard

How do you copy something to the clipboard in a Windows 8.1 apps? I couldn't find any API to do this? You could do it in the old Silverlight apps, but there seems to be no way now.

Is there any workaround? I want share some strings from one app which could be used by any other app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clipboard API for WP8.1 but it is available for Windows 8.1 apps. You need to either use a silverlight library which helps in setting content on clipboard or use share charm.

Comment: Which silverlight library? What is share charm?

Comment: Sharecharm is sharing functionality by Windows platform and you can use it to share text, html, images and links. Silverlight library you need to look at nuget.

Comment: Thank you - can nuget be used even if your UI is not silverlight? Also will it work on both 8.1 & 10?

Comment: Yes nuget packages are available for WP8.1 and Windows 10 both. You can use there only thing which limits the use is compatibility of package to Windows Target version i.e. package needs to be compatible to Windows 8.1 and 10 to use in Windows 8.1 and 10

Comment: Is this the package you are referring to - https://www.nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkit-Input/?

Comment: Which is the best to use? And what are all the others?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really possible with the old 8.1 API, but the Charming Share Clipboard API is probably your best bet here for attempting it.

Can you perhaps upgrade your App to the newer Windows 10 UWP API which natively supports it? This would be fairly easy and give you better hardware compatibility also.

[Clipboard API](http://peterfoot.net/2014/04/30/clipboard-api-for-windows-phone-8-1/)

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/InTheHand.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer/8.2014.4.301  - the owner seems to have unlisted it

Comment: Vast majority of Windows phones are on 8.1 as of now - no app can not support 8.1

Comment: I didn't realise so many were still on 8.1, we moved all our apps to UWP and our sales have only increased. But I understand. It seems there isn't really a way to achieve what you want then.